# Ошибка при запуске проекта

Tags: c#

Решил работать с C# (сразу проблемы): выбивает ошибку в C#:

[image: Ошибка при запуске проекта]

Вот сам код программы...

```
using System;
class TestApp
{
    static void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Ypa C3 pa6otaet");
    }
}
```

Comment: код непричём, чини .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похожая проблема описана [здесь](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390372/en):

> The application may crash when you run a .NET Framework 4.0-based application that uses the Diasymreader.dll component.

Для исправления нужно загрузить и установить [исправление](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390372/en). Кроме того, возможно повреждение самой установки Visual Studio, это можно проверить собрав и выполнив ваш пример из командной строки:

> `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe example.cs`
> `example.exe`

Если это так, то переустанавливать нужно Visual Studio, если нет, то переустанавливать нужно .NET Framework.